# TYPO3 CMS Page Tree Copying Isn't Working

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to copy a working TYPO3 page tree from one location to other. I can copy.. But while pasting only the first page is getting loaded, that is the root page.

I've increased the level of page copy settings in 'User Settings' Tab of the user. But still not working!!  If anybody do have a clue.. Please share.

Using **TYPO3 v7.6.15**.

Comment: Can you describe how you actually try to copy a tree? Do you use drag and drop (with CTRL-key to copy instead of move), do you use the context menu, ...

Comment: Yea, @JigalvanHemert. I used the contextmenu.

Comment: how big is the subtree to the page you want to copy? how many pages on 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... sublevel? how many records are in that pages on average (tt_content, news, ...)? does that error occur on every page copy that includes subpages or only on larger subtrees?

Comment: This happens in each.. page copy. Whether it's lengthy (with respect to levels) with much contents or short with less contents, this happens everywhere.. Except blank pages !

Comment: Can't reproduce. Just tried it with and without a high value for the "Recursive copy" setting and both work as expected.
Did you log out and log in again? Some settings only work correctly after logging in again.

Comment: Yea. Done. And issue is still there

Comment: Did you check for PHP errors in the php error log (e.g. timeout)? Did you check the webserver log for any errors (e.g. max input vars, etc).